# Kotlin coroutines & JavaMail blocking IO

Tags: java, kotlin, imap, coroutine

I'm experimenting with Kotlin coroutines to write a high performance IMAP client interacting with potentially 1,000's of mail boxes at the same time.

I'm using JavaMail to do the IMAP protocol work and it uses blocking IO.

Does that make my Kotlin coroutines effectively one-per-thread?